# Retrieving data from xml.

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xmltodict

I have an xml file through which I have to retrieve xml document.
Below is the xml document i have.

```
-<orcid-message>
   -<orcid-profile type="user">
      -<orcid-activities>
         -<orcid-works>
            -<orcid-work put-code="23938140" visibility="public">
               -<work-contributors>
                  -<contributor>
                       -<credit-name visibility="public">Tania Maes</credit-name>
                  -<contributor>
                       -<credit-name visibility="public">Francisco Avila Cobos</credit-name>
                  -<contributor>
                       -<credit-name visibility="public">Franco Liala Manus</credit-name>
```

I want to retrieve the contributor name:
I have tried so far:

```
contributors_name = (doc['orcid-message']['orcid-profile']
                        ['orcid-activities']['orcid-works']
                        ['orcid-work']['work-contributors']
                        ['contributor']['credit-name']  )

print(contributors_name)
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: What is `doc` variable? How did you populate it?

Comment: doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
and fd is the xml document

Comment: And what's the problem with your current code? Nothing get printed or any exception thrown?

Comment: contributors_name = (doc['orcid-message']['orcid-profile']['orcid-activities']['orcid-works']['orcid-work']['work-contributors']['contributor']['credit-name'] )
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str  : I get this eeror.

Answer (score 0):

> *"`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` : I get this error"*

The error message suggests that the problem was due to the XML containing multiple `contributor` elements, hence your code up to `['contributor']` part will return a list, which in turn can't be accessed directly by key (i.e `['credit-name']`) like a dictionary. You need to pick one item in the list from which you want to get `credit-name`, for example from the first item :

```
contributors = doc['orcid-message']['orcid-profile'] \
    ['orcid-activities']['orcid-works'] \
    ['orcid-work']['work-contributors'] \
    ['contributor']
contributor_name = contributors[0]['credit-name']
```

Or you can use list comprehension to get `credit-name` from all contributors :

```
contributors_name = [contrib['credit-name']['#text'] for contrib in contributors]
print(contributors_name)
```

**output :**

```
[u'Tania Maes', u'Francisco Avila Cobos', u'Franco Liala Manus']
```

Comment: I still get the same error. When i assign: contributors = doc['orcid-message']['orcid-profile'] ['orcid-activities']['orcid-works'] ['orcid-work']['work-contributors'] ['contributor']. It gives the same error.

Comment: Does the actual XML contains multiple elements of the same name, other than `contributor`, that mentioned in the code in your comment?

Comment: Yes, it does contain. May be i should use E-tree lib. which lib did u use to get the output?

Comment: `xmltodict` since the question is using this library. But in my test, only `contributor` and `credit-name` are multiple (based on XML snippet posted in question), so it worked fine.